# Responsive grid of absolute squares

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an responsive grid of absolutely defined squares. By that, I mean that I need the squares to be in certain positions within their parent element, and so when the page re-sizes I want the squares to scale with their parent but not to shift between lines.

Say for instance, I have a grid of 3x3 squares:

```
----------------
| A  | B  | C  |
----------------
| D  | E  | F  |
----------------
| G  | H  | I  |
----------------
```

I need the whole thing to be able to resize easily, with the rows and columns of the squares inside staying the same.

I've had a couple of tries at this, but I always run into problems getting the heights to work well.

If you have any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated!

John

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function resizeChild(){
  var wid = $('.child:first').width();
  $('.child').css('height', wid);
}
$(function(){
  resizeChild();
  $(window).resize(resizeChild);
});
```

```css
.parent{
  max-width: 900px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.child{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child::after{
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">a</div>
  <div class="child">b</div>
  <div class="child">c</div>
  <div class="child">d</div>
  <div class="child">e</div>
  <div class="child">f</div>
  <div class="child">g</div>
  <div class="child">h</div>
  <div class="child">i</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/dkeccbwo/

I don't know if you are going to have text or images as content, so this is as far as I can take it right now. You of course need to adjust more to your liking and purpose:

```
<div class="myrow">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
</div>

<div class="myrow">
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
</div>

<div class="myrow">
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myrow {width:100%;border:1px dashed grey; margin-bottom:10px;display:table;}
.box {width:29%;min-height:80px;float:left;margin:2%;background-color:#cecece;}
```

[image]

IN the div.box you can add square images that are set to be width:100% and then they will scale down and keep the aspect ratio.

**OR you may like to use tables** (yes, for some content and purposes tables are still worth to look into). For instance a Bootstrap table if you already use Bootstrap CSS: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables